# Is it possible to access enclosing context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

There are essentially three ways to use the with statement:

Use an existing context manager:

```
with manager:
    pass
```

Create a context manager and bind its result to a variable:

```
with Manager() as result:
    pass
```

Create an context manager and discard its return value:

```
with Manager():
    pass
```

If we have place a function `get_manager()` inside the three with blocks above, is there any implementation that can return the enclosing context manager, or at least their `__exit__` function?

It's obviously easy in the first case, but I can't think of a way to make it work in the other two. I doubt it's possible to get the entire context manager, since the value stack is popped immediately after the `SETUP_WITH` opcode. However, since the `__exit__` function is stored on the block stack by [`SETUP_WITH`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-SETUP_WITH), is there some way to access it?

Comment: Are you just curious about this, or do you have an actual use case you want to solve with this?

Comment: I do have an actual use case, but it's pretty involved. What it boils down to is that I need to be able to run the `__exit__` function without control leaving the enclosed block. I know that might sound like a terrible idea, but let's just go with it.

Comment: That really sounds like a bad idea because when the enclosed block then ends, the exit function would be called again. For many context managers this could likely cause some weird effects. Is there anything that prevents you from just passing the context itself further?

Comment: Yes, like I said, I know it sounds bad. In my case, doesn't always leave the enclosing scope, and I don't write the code that creates the context manager. Thanks for taking the time to help find the root of my question! This really is necessary, so let's hope someone has an answer.

Comment: You might be able to do what you want by inspecting `inspect.stack()`. `super` uses something similar in Python 3 to avoid the usually-redundant arguments, so I'm not going to just assume what you want to do is a bad idea, but it is almost certainly a bad idea. Try your hardest to avoid needing to do it. "doesn't always leave the enclosing scope" - I'm going to assume you meant to have the word "control" before that. Why doesn't control leave the scope? It usually does; even with, say, an unfinished generator, you can `close` the generator to run `finally` and `__exit__` blocks.

Comment: If you don't write the code that creates the context manager, can you talk to the person who does?

Comment: Even if you have no control over the context manager, surely you have control over the `with` block. So, why not just use #2 instead of #3? Then you have the thing returned from `__enter__`. And, if the context manager is buggy and that return value is not useful, why not write one extra line of code and use #1 instead?

Comment: @user2357112: `super()` uses a closure (explicitly set by the compiler) to achieve access to the class object; there is no equivalent for context managers. Besides, you can have multiple context managers active anywhere on the stack. What the OP is trying to do is **not** possible. Just rewrite the code using the CM to use case #1, always, and be done with it.

Comment: Of course, most context managers can't be rewritten to use the first form. `open()`, for example.

Comment: @Narcolei: What do you mean?  You can certainly write `x = open(...)` and then `with x:` and it works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, as discussed in the comments, this is not possible in all cases. When a context manager is created, the [following code is run](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/75c0b65591fd/Python/ceval.c#l2541) (in cPython 2.7, at least. I can't comment on other implementations):

```
    case SETUP_WITH:
    {
        static PyObject *exit, *enter;
        w = TOP();
        x = special_lookup(w, "__exit__", &exit);
        if (!x)
            break;
        SET_TOP(x);
        /* more code follows... */
    }
```

The `__exit__` method is pushed onto a stack with the `SET_TOP` macro, which is [defined as](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/75c0b65591fd/Python/ceval.c#l826):

```
#define SET_TOP(v)        (stack_pointer[-1] = (v))
```

The stack pointer, in turn, is set to the top of the frame's value stack at the start of [frame eval](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/75c0b65591fd/Python/ceval.c#l937):

```
stack_pointer = f->f_stacktop;
```

Where f is a frame object defined in [frameobject.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/75c0b65591fd/Include/frameobject.h). Unfortunately for us, this is where the trail stops. The python accessible frame object is defined with the [following methods only](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/75c0b65591fd/Objects/frameobject.c#l17):

```
static PyMemberDef frame_memberlist[] = {
    {"f_back",          T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_back),    RO},
    {"f_code",          T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_code),    RO},
    {"f_builtins",      T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_builtins),RO},
    {"f_globals",       T_OBJECT,       OFF(f_globals), RO},
    {"f_lasti",         T_INT,          OFF(f_lasti),   RO},
    {NULL}      /* Sentinel */
};
```

Which, unfortunaltey, does not include the `f_valuestack` that we would need. This makes sense, since `f_valuestack` is of the type `PyObject **`, which would need to be wrapped in an object to be accessible from python any way.

TL;DR: The `__exit__` method we're looking for is only located in one place, the value stack of a frame object, and cPython doesn't make the value stack accessible to python code.

Answer (score 5):

If the context manager is a class and only ever has a single instance, then you could find it on the heap:

```
import gc

class ConMan(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print "enter %s" % self.name

    def found(self):
        print "You found %s!" % self.name

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print "exit %s" % self.name


def find_single(typ):
    single = None
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(obj, typ):
            if single is not None:
                raise ValueError("Found more than one")
            single = obj
    return single



def foo():
    conman = find_single(ConMan)
    conman.found()

with ConMan('the-context-manager'):
    foo()
```

*(Disclaimer: Don't do this)*

Comment: Extra disclaimer: No, really, **don't** do this.  It is O(n) in the number of objects on the heap, which is potentially huge.  Translation: This has the potential to be extremely slow.  That's not even accounting for the possibility of finding random uncollected garbage and other junk you don't want.

Comment: I love this, it's perfectly evil.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between this case and similar-appearing cases like `super` is that here there is no enclosing frame to look at. A `with` statement is not a new scope. `sys._getframe(0)` (or, if you're putting the code into a function, `sys._getframe(1)`) will work just fine, but it'll return you the exact same frame you have before and after the `with` statement.

The only way you could do it would be by inspecting the bytecode. But even that won't help. For example, try this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def silly():
    yield

with silly():
    fr = sys._getframe(0)

dis.dis(fr.f_code)
```

Obviously, as [`SETUP_WITH`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-SETUP_WITH) explains, the method does get looked up and pushed onto the stack for [`WITH_CLEANUP`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-WITH_CLEANUP) to use later. So, even after `POP_TOP` removes the return value of `silly()`, its `__exit__` is still on the stack.

But there's no way to get at that from Python. Unless you want to start munging the bytecode, or digging apart the stack with `ctypes` or something, it might as well not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is just repeating what I said in my question.

Comment: @Narcolei: No it isn't. Your answer seems to assume that there's some kind of scope you could get at, and you want to know how. There is no such scope. Blocks are not scopes in Python, or really _anything_ once you get past the compiler stage; all the interpreter does is push a callable on the stack and call it. There's no hidden information buried anywhere for you to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you will accept a hacky solution, I bring you one inspired by [this](https://pretagteam.com/question/python-context-manager-for-temporary-variable-assignment).

Have the context manager edit the local namespace.

```py
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self, locals_reference):
        self.prev_context = locals_reference.get('context', None)
        self.locals_reference = locals_reference

    def __enter__(self):
        self.locals_reference['context'] = self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        if self.prev_context is not None:
            self.locals_reference['context'] = self.prev_context
        else:
            del self.locals_reference['context']
```

You can then get the context with the context variable

```py
with Context(locals()):
    print(context)
```

This implementation also works on nested contexts

```py
with Context(locals()):
    c_context = context
    with Context(locals()):
        print(c_context == context)
    print(c_context == context)
```

However this is implementation specific, as the return value of `locals` may be a copy of the namespace. Tested on CPython 3.10.

Edit:

The implementation above will not work in functions from other modules (I wonder why), so here is a function that fetches the context:

```py
def get_current_context(cls) -> "Context | None":
    try:
        if context is not None:
            return context
    except NameError:
        pass

    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            c = sys._getframe(i).f_locals.get('context',None)
        except ValueError:
            return None

        if c is not None:
            return c
        i += 1
```

I would make it a `classmethod` of the context manager class.

Answer (score 0):

Many years late, here's a straightforward way to do this in the second of the OP's 3 cases, where `with ... as` is used to bind the output of the context manager's `__enter__` method to a variable.  You can have the `__enter__` method return the context manager itself, or its `__exit__` method if that's all you're interested in.

```py
class Manager:
     def __enter__(self): return self
     def __exit__(self, *args): print("Doing exit method stuff!")

with Manager() as manager:
    print("Doing some stuff before manually calling the exit method...")
    manager.__exit__() # call the exit method
    print("Doing some more stuff before exiting for real...")
```

Of course, this would interfere with using `with ... as` to bind some other return-value from `__enter__`, but it would be straightforward to have `__enter__` return a tuple consisting of its ordinary return value and the manager, just as you can make a function return multiple values.

As the OP noted, it's also straightforward to call the `__exit__` method in the first case, where the context manager had already been assigned to a variable beforehand.  So the only really tricky case is the third one where the context manager is simply created via `with Manager():` but is never assigned to a variable.  My advice would be: if you're going to want to refer to the manager (or its methods) later, then either (1) assign it a name beforehand, (2) have its `__enter__` method return a reference to it for `with ... as` to capture as I did above, but (3) DO NOT create it without storing any reference to it!